# how to save best model in timeseries tsai

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series

I am using tsai TSCLassifier to train on my data.
However I donot know how to save the best model of all epochs.Like there is modelcheckpoint in keras/tensorflow. Among all epochs I want to save the model that is best val_loss on test set.

Below is my code, can somebody please help to let me know how to save best model in tsai library.

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
from pickle import load
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np
from tsai.all import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve

dataset_idx = 0
X_train = load(open(r"X_train_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
y_train = load(open(r"y_train_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
X_test = load(open(r"X_test_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
y_test = load(open(r"y_test_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
print("dataset loaded")

learn = TSClassifier(X_train, y_train, arch=InceptionTimePlus, arch_config=dict(fc_dropout=0.5))

print("training started")
learn.fit_one_cycle(5, 0.0005)
learn.export("tsai_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the implementation that worked for me.

```
dataset_idx = 0
print("training info:", dataset_idx)
X_train = load(open(r"X_train_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb')).transpose((0,2,1))
y_train = load(open(r"y_train_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
X_test = load(open(r"X_test_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb')).transpose((0,2,1))
y_test = load(open(r"y_test_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
l = X_train.shape[0]
X = np.concatenate([X_train,X_test],axis=0)
del X_train, X_test
y = np.concatenate([y_train,y_test],axis=0)
del y_train, y_test
print("dataset loaded")
learn = TSClassifier(X, y, splits = [(list(range(l))), (list(range((l), y.shape[0])))], arch=InceptionTimePlus, bs=256, arch_config=dict(fc_dropout=0.5))
print("training started")
learn.fit_one_cycle(20, 0.001, cbs=SaveModelCallback(monitor='valid_loss', fname="ITP_"+str(dataset_idx)))
```